# What is the best practice of handling views for a simple news app?

Tags: android

I have a simple app where in the main activity, user is presented with a long list of news. Each item in the list contains an image and a title. When the user taps on an item, a page that contains a more detailed article opens. User is able to slide right(with animation) or press back button(without animation) to go back to the news list.

How should I construct this behavior?

I am confident that a single activity is sufficient and I don't need to create a second activity for the details page.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `RecyclerView` and a `FrameLayout` to `ViewPager` when an item is clicked jump to the `FrameLayout`.

If you want to delete an item from `RecyclerView`, just call

`adapter.notifyItemRemoved(int position);`

Answer (score 1):

I created a similar app before. The idea here is to have the `MainActivity` gather and display the news list and create an event listener to `ListView` or `RecyclerView` and start a new activity. The second activity is responsible for a more detailed version of that specific news. So pass the `News` object to construct the view. If you are in `Kotlin` you can use this lib for easier activity transactions [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko).

For the Activity animations/transition I advice to use this [Activity Transition using Shared Elements](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity) for more detailed tutorial, you can refer [at this Medium tutorial](https://medium.com/@ishanfx/android-shared-element-activity-transition-9c2501cd79ec) (which also helped me before.)

Comment: OP is asking for a single Activity option. Please read the question properly and don't pollute the answer with additional animation/transaction tutorials. That obscures the purpose of question

Comment: Yes I read that. But Im thinking to fully maximize the Android Transition lifecycle which normal apps do. So basically this is an idea from someone who made it.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue with you, just trying to simplify the Q&A since the future reader will get a pinch of this thread. Activity is easier to maintain but single Activity for this case is the way to go as OP stated. You can simply use Fragment if your components are not heavily dependent on the lifecycle events

Comment: You got a point. Ill update my post with all Activity - Fragment version. Thanks for lookin out.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, for your case single activity is the right choice. However, `ViewPager` is not what you're looking for. The main purpose of `ViewPager` is to show views that have a "sibling" relationship. For example, if you want to show news depending on the country you can you use `ViewPager` to categorize news, a country per `ViewPager` section. If you want to show details of news when an item is clicked, `ViewPager` is not the right option. What would you do instead is to add `NewsDetailsFragment` programmatically on top of `NewsListFragment`.

**To cut short.**

Say you populate your `NewsListFragment` in `onCreate()` and want to add a `NewsDetailsFragment` to `MainActivity`, then you can use below approach.

```
    public class MainActivity extend AppCompatActivity{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Budnle savedInstance){
            super.onCreate(savedInstance);
            // add your NewsListFrgament here
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_framelayout, newListFragment).commit();    
        }

        // Pseudo click action. Will be triggered when item in NewsListFragment is clicked
        @Ovverride
        public void onNewsListItemClicked(Int newsId){  
        // Add NewsDetailsFragment
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction.add(R.id.container_framelayout, newsDetailsFragment).commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I implemented this. Now how can I implement "swipe right to go back" functionality? Everything I tried so far is funky and slow unlike how a viewpager handles it.

Comment: Please, add your code or a thorough explanation of what you've tried so far. There is a way to implement it; by adding swipe to your layout which I'll post the answer tomorrow because it'll take some to test it. But before that, I just wanna highlight that "swipe to go back" is not in Android's default design list. You can find few apps that use "swipe to go back" functionality. I believe you've got that idea from iOS and would recommend to reconsider it. If you insist to have that functionality, I'll post the answer, as I said. Remind me after about 9-10 hours, please